# Is this the best way to share Api Data across the APP?

Tags: reactjs, react-native

So, I am new to react Native and I am taking over code that was written like 5 years ago for a react Native App. Since I know things moved a lot since then I want to make sure I follow best practices.

So basically, API responses are saved in a state.

Then for each screen, there is a StackNavigator using `createStackNavigator`
The render method in those stack navigator look like this

```
import { InfoContainer } from "../api/InfoContainer ";
....
....
....
  render() {
    return (
      <Subscribe
        to={[ InfoContainer ]}
      >
        {(InfoStore) => (
          <SettingsStack
            navigation={this.props.navigation}
            screenProps={{
              store: InfoStore,
            }}
          />
        )}
      </Subscribe>
    );
  }
}
```

Then there is a tabNavigator.js that aggregates all the StackNavigators for each screen
and it looks like this

```
export default createBottomTabNavigator(
  {
    Overview: {
      screen: HomeStack,
      navigationOptions: {
        title: "Home",
      },
```

then on that screen, the API data is accessed like this

```
await InfoStore.fetchInfo(currentUser);
```

if someone could advise of what's the best way to do this and refer to some documentation or article as I could not find anything relevent.